# v-bind class on button click gets removed

Tags: vue.js

I been having a strange error that im not sure why it happens. Basically, if I pass the class name as a props to the child component, once the button is clicked the button loses all its layout. This does not happen if I hardcode the class name inside the child component. What is the reason for this behavior?

Parent component

```
<button-layout
    btn-type="button"
    btn-class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"
    :btn-text="arrSize.size"
    :key="index"
    v-on:getBtnClicked="testMe($event, index)"
    :is-active="index === btnClicked"
>
</button-layout>
```

Child component

```
 <button
        :type="btnType"
        :class="btnClass" //if I move this to class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" the problem doest happen
        v-on:click="returnClickedButton($event)"
        v-bind:class="{active: isActive}">
    {{btnText}}
</button>
```

Comment: don't u need the colon character : in front of btn-class & btn-type?

Comment: I dont think so because im passing a string and not a variable.

Comment: are u defining props inside the child component?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. I could have just declared the class inside the button layout initiation like this

```
<button-layout
  btn-type="button"
  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" //declaring class in here instead of passing as props
  :btn-text="arrSize.size"
  :key="index"
  v-on:getBtnClicked="testMe($event, index)"
  :is-active="index === btnClicked"
>
</button-layout>
```